# Any limitation on array size in Arduino Mega 2560?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, array, memory-usage, data-type

I am writing an Arduino code with 3 arrays.

Two of those are *double* and other one is *int*. Further first two arrays have nearly 420 elements **for each**.
Now I noticed that with more that 89 elements on 3rd array the program stall, and stuck executing. But with 89 or less number of element it runs with out an issue.

What would be the issue?

Comment: That's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: The limit is 32767 elements. Anything else is a problem with your code.

Comment: Also be sure to not be too close to the max memory. If there is not enough space left to put variables on the stack, the program will crash some way

Comment: Are these arrays declared by size at compile time? what does the IDE report as far as your memory use is concerted when it compiles the program. As stated before, kinda hard to help without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

A Mega has 8 KB of memory.

You are using:

- double (same as float on an Arduino, see [double](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/)) , 4 bytes * 420 elements * 2 arrays = 3,360 bytes
- int (2 bytes) * 89 = 178 bytes

In total this is 3,538 bytes

This is about 50%, so I'm unsure what the 'rest' is.
You can take a look at the other related question that may show some answers (like using dynamic memory, memory gaps, or local/stack variables): [What are the traditional ways to optimize program memory usage?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76619/what-are-the-traditional-ways-to-optimize-program-memory-usage/76620#76620)